# Why I can't use isset() with laravel $request->input('key')

Tags: php, laravel, post, laravel-5, get

These two snippets are the same

1)

```
if(isset($request->input('optionId'))){
  ....
  ....
  ....
  // statements will go here 
}
```

2)

```
$optionId = $request->input('optionId');

if(isset($optionId)){
  ....
  ....
  ....
  // statements will go here 
}
```

when first attempt, IDE says there is a syntax error. When I saved it and run the interpreter says

> "Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null
>   !== expression" instead)"

but the second one is executing fine.

my question is its the same when its assigned to $optionId right? Why is it running in second attempt and not in the first attempt .. what is the difference?

Comment: Read the '[*Determining If An Input Value Is Present*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests)' section.

Comment: ok i can use $request->has('optionId') . it helps . but it doesn't answer the question

Comment: That's why I never posted an answer, rather a comment because it addresses how it should be done not your actual question.

Comment: @NuOneTAttygalle answered your question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dig some and found the real cause. Thought to share ...

`isset()` is not a function. it is a language construct. 
Language constructs are the building blocks of a language. they are hard corded into the parser. so we cant redefine those. So `isset()` is hard corded into the parser to accept only variables. Thats why any statements cannot parse to `isset()`. if do thats the reason for the `Syntax error`

functions on the other hand have mapped to a set of language constructs. parser allows to change that mapping at compile or runtime.

summary is -> parser is the one who is dealing with **language constructors** and the built-in functions are mapped and simplified to a set of language constructs before parsing.

Comment: Yes, isset is just another language construct just like if, echo, die and return. Being able to call `echo` as `echo()` is what confuses people and makes them think that they are functions

Answer (score 5):

You can use `$request->has('optionId')` instead.

And to answer your actual question, PHP Documentation has already warned about it.

> isset() only works with variables as passing anything else will result
>   in a parse error

Ref: [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php#refsect1-function.isset-notes)

Comment: changed back to `parse` error from `syntax` error, as document clearly suggests that. I have literally copy-pasted it. If you still think your suggestion is right, please go ahead and suggest the change in PHP Documentation, that would help many. :)

Comment: parse error happens because of a syntax error. When I was coding, ide warned about a syntax error. When compiler tries to parse a code which have a syntax error then the result will be a parse error. so In  interpreted language, (PHP, ASP, etc.) the parse error happens when the code is run because it is compiled and run at the same time. so syntax and parse both errors occurs in this context

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using PHP 5.6+ version, expressions supported for `isset()` function only since 5.6 versions